# Geoserver GET request to the REST API without authentication

Tags: geoserver, rest, json, jquery

I am using Geoserver to serve a number of WMS layers.  I am using jQuery's [$.getJson](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)('/geoserver/rest//featuretype.json') to programmatically populate a table with the available layers and their abstracts ([Geoserver REST API](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/restconfig/rest-config-api.html)).  I am also iterating over a Geoserver [reflect](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/wmsreflector.html) request to generate thumbnails.  At this point, this requires authentication.

Is it possible to access this information through the REST interface without authentication?

Should I be making these request through [PHP, Python, or cURL](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/restconfig/rest-config-examples/index.html), instead of directly calling the URL in the JS?

I understand the need to authenticate some of the REST URLs as they provide the login and password for the postgis backend in plain text.

Comment: I don't think you can get something similar to WMS functionality by using Geoserver REST API. However I did not understand why a get request over WMS in your Geoserver requires authentication while the getJson (as I see from the link it is http get as well) is working fine. I mean if you think the reason is postgis backend still you are hitting it in both requests...
In any case making a request to WMS by POST and adding the authentication information in that request might work.

Comment: I was able to get this functionality through a python cgi script.  I too am stumped about where authentication actually kicks in.  I should be able to use GET requests without ever needing to authenticate.  At the same time, postGIS DB login/pass are stored in geoserver (and accessible via GET apparently)...

Comment: For the down voter, let me know how this question can be improved to increase the potential to get a high quality answer.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Geoserver are you using?
To avoid the authentication just go to the "authentication" page in the security menu of the web-admin, select "REST" from the filter chain and check "no security" :)

- [Geoserver manual](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/index.html)
- [REST Configuration](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/service.html#rest-services)